# I am using bootstrap by downloading it locally and its not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap  by running it locally and its not working. But when i am using with CDN link, its working. Can anyone help me out in this?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Home</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
   </head>
<body>
       <form class="row g-3">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <label for="inputEmail4" class="form-label">Email</label>
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail4">
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="gridCheck">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="gridCheck">
              Check me out
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Sign in</button>
        </div>
      </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Note:~ The bootsrap.min.css and bootstrap.min.js file is in the folder itself where i am running this project.

Comment: Why `bootstrap-4`? I highly recommend you to upgrade (download) a newer version of Bootstrap 5.x

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try prepending `./` before filename. like this

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">
<script src="./bootstrap.min.js"> </script>
```